# Rails : scope for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, named-scopes

I have 2 models Person and PersonInterest : 
People contains all the information about a person
Person Interests stores the interests of a person (person_id, interest_id)

Person has_many PersonInterests

How would I create a scope that can search through all people with the same interest_id

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. You need to create a join like so :

```
Person.joins(person_interests).where(:person_interests => {interest_id = 1})
```